# How to get "export to mapserver map file" option in qgis 1.3.0 in lucid linux?

Tags: ubuntu, mapserver, qgis

I am new to GIS and i want to export the qgis file to mapserver map file.
But that option is not available in my Qgis 1.3.0  mimas.
what to do to get it?
pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool is supposed to do that: [qgis2ms](http://spatialserver.net/qgis2ms/)